# laravel model static method. it is ok?

Tags: laravel, static-methods

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{

    protected $dates = ['due_date'];
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'project_id'];    

    public function scopeDueInDays($query,$days)
    {
        return $query->where('due_date', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()
        ->subDays($days));
    }
    static public function dueInDays($days)
    {
        return Task::where('due_date', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()
        ->subDays($days));
    }
}
```

I want to go to method definition on vscode editor.
I can't this with scopeMethod.

Then i create static method. it works. at least until now, fine.

can use static method like below

```
 $task = new Task;
 $tasks = $task->dueInDays($day)->get();
 $tasks = Task::dueInDays($day)->get();
```

this way is have problem on using laravel?

is anyone to using static method without scopeMethod?

Comment: If you are getting the result then no issue

Comment: If you want your IDE to recognise scopes you need some sort of Laravel plugin that supports them. But do use a scope. It is better. Also check out [laravel IDE helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) which might help

Comment: Thanks for answers.